# Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'userSubject' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'userSubject' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, rxjs

I want to call

```js
login(username, password) {    
  return Parse.User.logIn(username, password)
    .then(function (user) {
      // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
      localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
      console.log(user);
      this.userSubject.next(user);
      return user;
    });
}
```

same like this

```js
login(username, password) {
  return this.http.post<user>(`${environment.apiUrl}/users/authenticate`, { username, password })
    .pipe(map(user => {
      // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
      localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
      console.log(user);
      this.userSubject.next(user);
      return user;
  }));
}
```

but it is resulting in error

```
Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'userSubject' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'userSubject' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that you use a normal function instead of an arrow function.
a normal function has own `this` pointer.

simply use an arrow function instead.

```js
login(username, password) {

return Parse.User.logIn(username, password)
  .then((user) => { // <-- here is the change
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
    console.log(user);
    this.userSubject.next(user);
    return user;
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bro satan